# Hibernation, Standby, Shutdown or Lock when using the Laptop often

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown, hibernate, standby

I'm a student and have an ASUS Netbook with Win10. I have to change my location very often per day. Now I need to know what is the best way to do this when looking at battery, windows, usability, hardware, etc.

At the moment, I'm doing this via hibernate because I need the state which I had at shutdown (Opened Browser, PDF Reader, OneNote and some applications). I have around 10 minutes and 60minutes breaks between "shutdown" and reuse and use it every day

What would be the best option when looking at the things above?

Comment: Hibernation saves the current state and turns the device off.  Standby does not turn the device off.   Shutdown does save the current state.  Lock just keeps the device in a full power state.

Comment: @Ramhound  Shutdown does **not** save the current state ;)

Comment: Yes;  I meant to say it shuts the device off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best advice is to **not worry about it and just close your laptop lid when you're not using it**. But if you want the longest battery life possible, set the power option to power saver.

Reason: By default setting, if you close the laptop's lid, Windows will go to sleep mode, it only uses 2-3% battery per hour on my old laptop, or maybe less on newer netbook, and can quickly start within 2-10 seconds, without losing what you're doing. **However**, if the laptop is sleep within three hours, it will automatically went into hibernation, which doesn't use power at all, but takes longer times to boot again, while still keeping your current work.

So, don't worry about it, if you occasionally use the laptop, sleep works the best, if you aren't going to use it again for 30 minutes or so, hibernation is my favorite, but that's not necessary since **even if you're not hibernating it** or forgot about it, **it doesn't really matter**, it will go into hibernation by itself. Shut down is irrelevant these days except when installing program or windows update, locking is not a power option, it's just lock your laptop so no one can use it.

Comment: Windows 10 more or less instantly resumes from hibernation.  I am not sure I agree with the notion it will take longer to boot compared to sleep mode.

Comment: It definitely will take longer to boot from hibernation, but nowadays it is less noticeable since the age of SSD, depends on the hardware some still use HDD. Nevertheless it's always faster to load from RAM compared to any SSD/HDD.

Comment: I suppose I take it for granted that my Surface Pro 3 resumes from hibernation instantly.

Comment: Yup, your SP3 is an awesome machine that is really fast.